# Salesforce Ant retrieve referenced packages

Tags: ant, salesforce

I'm trying to use ant to retrieve all the information from a salesforce org so that I can examine and modify the data. I understand how to retrieve all of the components referenced in the Force.com Migration Tool Guide: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/daas/index.htm like CustomObjects, CustomFields, Layouts, etc. by editing the packages.xml file and using ant. When I use the Eclipse IDE however, I get a "referenced packages" folder that contains many different components that I was not able to get through ant. Is there a way to obtain these components through the use of ant?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the "Retrieving Managed or Unmanaged Packages" section of the Force.com Migration Tool Guide. It's this type of syntax:

```
<target name="retrieveNamedPackage">
<sf:retrieve
username="${sf.username}"
password="${sf.password}"
serverurl="${sf.serverurl}"
retrieveTarget="projectFolder"
packageNames="mySourcePackage"/>
</target>
```